# Fetch Json API data in Redux store and create recursive Dropdown

Tags: reactjs, recursion, react-redux, dropdown

I am new to React and I am trying to create a recursive nested dropdown from the Json Data fetched from my API, keeping it updated from the store. I couldn't find a good solution to this. Any suggestions?

Comment: So what did you try, how does your code look like currently?

Comment: I did define a reducer, actions, created a store and connected a component to it... but I have to find a good shape state to my application (I am fetching a list of elements(name, description, children of element) from my API, the user won't mofidy the elements, just select them from the dropdown. Then I need to display them using the component (I did not define the return function yet).

Comment: The data I am fetching is quite big, I guess I need to find a smart way (to fetch only the parents at first, then their children when selected for example).

Comment: I suggest you create two data structures, first the actual data with name and description as a flat list by identifier and then a nested structure that only uses identifiers for crearting the parent/child relation. So you have one relatively small structure with the relations and can grab the name/description from the flat structure as needed.